# How to connect jupyter notebook to my git repo?

Tags: python, git, jupyter

I'm using Anaconda and recently started to learn Jupyter Notebook. Just can't figure out, how to push my projects to git? (I'm currently just downloading and adding these files to git, and I believe it's not the best solution

Comment: Your notebooks are just ipynb files, so organize those however you like and create a repo for the directory in which they are held. I use VSCode for my jupyter IDE, file management, and git integration. How you want to do this though is up to you.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.